# How to implement "Ord" for algebraic data types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Imagine you have a rating like

```
Rating = OneStar | TwoStars | ThreeStars | FourStars | FiveStars
```

What is the best way to instanciate/implement "Ord" for such an algebraic data type in Haskell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way would be to just add `deriving (Eq, Ord)` to the type's definition.

Since you listed your constructors in ascending order, the derived `Ord` instance will give you exactly the order you want.

However, when the order of definitions does not match the comparison order you want and changing the order in the definition is not an option for some reason, you can still derive `Eq`, since for that the order does not matter. Given an instance of `Eq`, we can manually write an instance for `Ord`. The most succinct way to define `compare` would probably be to spell out all the combinations for which `compare` should return `LT` and then simply use `compare x y | x == y = Eq; compare _ _ = GT` for the remaining combinations.

Comment: Thanks, i did not know that the order is preserved.

Comment: Bonus question: what if the order in the definiton would not reflect the numerical order?

Comment: @Lenny: Then you'd have instantiate Ord and define `compare` by hand (assuming that changing the order in the definition is not an option for some reason) - you can still derive Eq though since for that the order does not matter. The most succinct way to define `compare` would probably be to spell out all the combinations for which compare should return LT and then simply use `compare x y | x == y = Eq; compare _ _ = GT` for the remaining combinations.

Comment: @Lenny easier solution: change the definition so it is in ascending order!

Comment: @Lenny for some protocol work I even added unused placeholders: `data x = Val0 | Val1 | Val2 | Unused3 | Unused4 | Val5`.  Silly, is just sometimes the fastest and easiest way to go (but not if you have large gaps, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

As has been mention, you can derive `Eq` and `Ord`.  Or you could derive `Enum` and then do

```
instance Eq Rating where
    x == y = fromEnum x == fromEnum y
```

Or just spell it all out

```
instance Eq Rating where
    OneStar == OneStar = True
    TwoStar == TwoStar = True
...
    _ == _ = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to implement `compare` is to fall back on a type that already is an instance of `Ord`.

```
data Rating = OneStar | TwoStars | ThreeStars | FourStars | FiveStars
    deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord Rating where
  compare x y = compare (r2n x) (r2n y)
    where
      r2n OneStar = 1
      r2n TwoStars = 2
      r2n ThreeStars = 3
      r2n FourStars = 4
      r2n FiveStars = 5
```

This solution scales pretty well, I think.